# Application Defined or Object defined error when setting data validation dynamically for a range

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to add data validation to a column dynamically in which the values for each cell dropdown are from another sheet.

Here is the code

```
Dim fRange As Range
Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = Sheets("Service_master").Cells(Sheets("Service_master").Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set fRange = Sheets("Service_master").Range("A2:A" & lRow)
Dim dRange As Range
lRow = Sheets("resource_master").Cells(Sheets("resource_master").Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set dRange = Sheets("resource_master").Range("G2:G" & lRow)
With dRange.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="=Service_master!" & fRange.Address
End With
```

But in .Add line where we are specifying the formular its triggering an error `Application defined or object-defined error`

The formula is "`=Service_master!$A$2:$A$6`" at that line.

At that sheet there is data in that range which I wants to be there for the dropdown or `resource_master`

Comment: Long shot: try to recompile your project (Debug->Compile VBA project). Normally your code should work (I have recreated it and it works for me)

Comment: Additionaly I would advise to change lRow from integer to Long.

Comment: Its strange it worked when I used R1C1 notation.

Comment: It does not works on A1 notation?  the code looks good

Comment: I copied the code into Excel 2016 and it seems to work fine..

Comment: Didnt understand why.. A1 notation keeps failing...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Totally crazy.. What I found is if we enable R1C1 notation in File -> Options, A1 notation wont work.. the same if we disable it, only A1 will work..